# Simple rewrite from root domain to subdirectory IIS7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I know the basics of how to rewrite but cant seem to find a rule that works the way I want it too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :o)

```
    <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?blah.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="blog/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Basically I want it to only rewrite:

- www.blah.com **-->** www.blah.com/blog
- blah.com **-->** www.blah.com/blog
- www.blah.com/blog **-->** do nothing.
- www.blah.com/any-thing-else **-->** do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding in a second condition to check PATH_INFO? Seeing as you only want to re-write when this is not specified...

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
```

The checks that PATH_INFO 'Does Not Match the Pattern' ^$ which is an empty string.

I'm not able to test this right now, so it might need tweaking...